# How can I link a page in a local PDF file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I load a PDF file when user clicks a button using jQuery, but it opens the document starting from the first page (as it is always).

I would like to link a specific page depending of the needed chapter. Is it there any way to do this nice to have thing?

Here is how I open the document:

```
$('#btnManual').click(function() {
    window.open('documentation/test.pdf');
});
```

Comment: `$('#btnManual').click(function() {
    window.open('documentation/test.pdf#page=4');
});`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To target an HTML link to a specific page in a PDF file, add `#page=[page number]` to the end of the link's URL.

For example, this HTML tag opens page 4 of a PDF file named myfile.pdf:

```
<A HREF="http://www.example.com/myfile.pdf#page=4">
```

More info: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html